Polarization of gravitational waves - Dirac's rotation operator
I refer to the page extracts below. I think my question is fully self-contained, but for background:

Dirac is dealing with the weak-gravity case and gravitational plane waves moving in the $l_\sigma$ direction.

The metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ satisfies the wave equation in harmonic coordinates $\eta^{\rho\sigma}g_{\mu\nu,\rho\sigma}=0$, and is a function of the single variable $l_\sigma x^\sigma$.

The function $u_{\mu\nu}$ is the derivative of $g_{\mu\nu}$ with respect to the variable $l_\sigma x^\sigma$. Also $u=u^\mu_\mu$.

In Chap. 34, Dirac assumes that the waves are traveling in the $x^3$ direction, so $l_0=1$, $l_1=0$, $l_2=0$, $l_3=-1$.

$u_{\mu\nu}$ is obviously a symmetric matrix. Based on the conditions for harmonic coordinates, Dirac derives a number of relations among the $u_{\mu\nu}$ as shown below.

The (Einstein) energy-momentum pseudotensor for the plane wave was derived in the previous chapter; it is $16\pi {t_\mu}^\nu = \frac{1}{2} \left( u_{\alpha\beta}u^{\alpha\beta} - \frac{1}{2}u^2 \right) l_\mu l^\nu$.


I suspect none of this matters to my question. On page 67 Dirac introduces the "infinitesimal rotation operator $R$ in the plane $x^1 x^2$." This is actually nothing more than the matrix which rotates a vector 90-degrees clockwise.
Then he begins "Applied to $u_{\alpha\beta}$ is has the effect..." and here he has lost me completely.

How is he defining $R$ applied to $u_{\alpha\beta}$? The $u_{\alpha\beta}$ are entries in a 4x4 matrix. What does $R$ mean in this context?

What is the significance of the eigenvalues of $iR$?

What does he mean by "... thus correspond to spin 2"?

How is this connected with the polarization of gravitational waves?

Why, incidentally, does he call $R$ the "infinitesimal rotation operator" when it is a 90-degree rotation?


Many thanks for any guidance here. The text is actually extremely readable and coherent from pages 1-66 ... unfortunately it's only on the third to last page that he loses the reader.


